# Flickity carousel rendering too large and creating horizontal scrolling in Nuxt/Tailwind application

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vue-flickity

I am using a carousel from Flickity in a Nuxt/Vue app styled with Tailwind. This carousel is in a 12 columns grid starting at the second columns and spanning 11 columns (ending on the right border of the screen). When I resize the screen I sometimes end up with a little bit of horizontal scrolling. I would like NOT to have this horizontal scrolling. Is there a way to do this ?
[image]

```html
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-12">
    <CarouselBase class="pl-95 col-start-2 col-span-11" >
        <ResourceCard
            v-for="(item, itemIndex) in items"
            :key="itemIndex"
            v-bind="item"
            class="mr-2"
        />
    </CarouselBase>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow? Please upvote if it did.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the padding (`pl-95`) fixed the horizontal scroll issue.